# ScreenRotation on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, screen-rotation

I want my APP on iPad that A-View is Portrait-only and B-View is Landscape(Left or Right)-only.

I tried [**application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:**] in my AppDelegate.m and [**shouldAutorotate:**][**supportedInterfaceOrientations:**][**preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation:**]in my NavigationController,ViewController which I used to show my APP(iOS 11).

It works well on iPhone, but when I try on iPad it doesn't work even [application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:].

I want know how to control ScreenRotation on iPad.

Thank you very much.
Appreciate for your kindness help.

---

solved, just keep for reminder

Answer (score 1):

iPad has the multipleScreen Function that it must support All-Rotation.
But when you check [Requires full screen]on Deployment Info, it means iPad now is full screen and the Rotation Function can work well.